# How can i apply a:hover CSS to H2, which is inside the same anchor tag?

Tags: css, hover

This was really tough to phrase the question. I hope it's good enough.

I have an `H2` inside of an `a` tag and am having problems with the `:hover` behavior of each. The `H2` wrapping around all *except* the word "View" is what my client wants.

What is happening, is after the H2 CSS i created, the "View" and the "Mad Science of Colorado Coupon" are both turning white on `:hover`, but when you hover over the `a`, only the word "View" is changing, not the entire link. If you hover over the other words, the entire link is changing.

How can i better code this as to have the everything inside the `anchor` change to `#fff` when you hover over any part of it?

```css
.coupon-box {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffff9d;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.coupon-box:hover {
  background: #ff6138 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*  h2  */

h2.coupon-wrapper {
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}


/*Hover for h2 and a */

a:hover,
h2.coupon-wrapper:hover {
  background: #ff6138 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
/* HTML */
<div class="coupon-box">
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:60px;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center">
          <a href="#">View <h2 class="coupon-wrapper">Mad Science of Colorado Coupon</h2></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what you really want is to learn about bundling and capturing https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 2):

Simply update the hover like this:

```
a:hover, /*Update the content of a on hover on a*/
a:hover h2.coupon-wrapper /*Update the content of h2 on hover on a*/
```

Full code

```css
.coupon-box {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ffff9d;
  text-align: center;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-top: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.coupon-box:hover {
  background: #ff6138 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*  h2  */

h2.coupon-wrapper {
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  color: #6c6c6c;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}


/*Hover for h2 and a */

a:hover,
a:hover h2.coupon-wrapper {
  background: #ff6138 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="coupon-box">
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="height:60px;vertical-align:middle;text-align:center">
          <a href="#">View <h2 class="coupon-wrapper">Mad Science of Colorado Coupon</h2></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```